# Excel vba-- macro to add a new comment and set focus to that comment

Tags: vba, excel

I'd like to imitate the behavior of the default insert comment button with a macro. I want to store all of my macros in the Personal workbook, not the active workbook. 
I'd like it to simply create a comment and then set the focus to that empty comment. 
Below is what I have so far, using Terry's suggestion to make the comment `.Visible` and then `.Shape.Select` it:

```
    Sub addNewComment()
    Dim authorName As String
    Dim authorNameLength As Integer

    authorName = Application.UserName
    authorNameLength = Len(authorName)

    ActiveCell.AddComment _
    authorName & ":" _
    & Chr(10)
            With ActiveCell.Comment
                With .Shape
                    .AutoShapeType = msoShapeFoldedCorner
                    .Fill.ForeColor.RGB = RGB(215, 224, 239)
                    With .TextFrame
                        .AutoSize = True
                        .Characters.Font.Size = 11
                        .Characters.Font.Name = "Calibri"
                        .Characters(1, (authorNameLength + 1)).Font.Bold = True
                        .Characters((authorNameLength + 2), 1).Font.Bold = False
                    End With
                End With
                .Visible = True
                .Shape.Select True
            End With
End Sub
```

I'm not sure how to get the comment to go back to not being visible. Do I store the reference to the cell I just added the comment to, and then refer to that cell with the `Worksheet_SelectionChange` event? Or do I make that event just hide all comments on the sheet? Is it possible to use `Worksheet_SelectionChange` at all with the Personal workbook?
Also, my comment box does not resize as I type and add line breaks. It does resize after I exit, but actually too large by about four lines. Not sure why that is happening.
I'm sure there is a cleaner way to organize my With blocks as well.

I tried using the following to hide the comment again after selecting another cell:

```
 Private Sub Worksheet_SelectionChange(ByVal Target As Range)
    Target.Comment.Visible = False
End Sub
```

I received the following error:

[error 91: Object variable or With block variable not set](https://i.stack.imgur.com/g9X2Z.png)

Answer (score 1):

You can select the comment once you make it visible using the following:

```
With range("a1")
    .Comment.Visible = True
    .Comment.Shape.Select True
End With
```

But I think you'll need to have another macro to hide the comment again once you deselect, as otherwise it will stay visible.  You could try doing this on the SelectionChange event of the worksheet:

```
 Private Sub Worksheet_SelectionChange(ByVal Target As Range)
    Target.Comment.Visible = False
End Sub
```

Comment: OK so your method is I think on the right track. I'm trying to post my code the way I have it right now. my issue is that I am trying to make the comment add to whatever the active cell is. which worked fine. your method of selecting the cell after making it visible worked well. however, the comment box does not auto size as i type, and also i need to be able to make that specific cell no longer visible, not necessarily a1.

Comment: Sorry I just re-read your question.  You can use the Target within the selectionChange event to get the cell you just left.  i.e. Target.Comment

Comment: Oh so selection change event target refers to the cell you just left, not the cell you select next?

Comment: yeah the Target reference is the cell before the event, so in this case the active cell prior to changing cells.

Comment: OK this is great so far. Is there a way to use a `Worksheet_SelectionChange` event that is saved in the Personal workbook rather than in each workbook being used? Would declaring it as a public sub accomplish that? Or can the code you posted be placed in the Personal workbook and still affect other active workbooks?

Comment: I cant think of a way of storing the macro in the personal book and still having it trigger on selection changes.  The best you can probably do is store it in your personal book then bind it to a taskbar button that you can click.

Comment: When I use the 
 `Private Sub Worksheet_SelectionChange(ByVal Target As Range)
    Target.Comment.Visible = False
End Sub`
I get an error '91' : Object variable or With block variable not set
and the comment remains visible.

Comment: It might be that this errors when you are moving from cells that don't have comments.  You might need to put it in an IF statement that is only True if the cell has a comment